# Remove coordinate objects from xarray.Dataset?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have a xarray.Dataset as shown in the bottom figure.
I would like to remove 'Empty' coordinate objects from the Dataset.
How can I do that?
A sample code is attached (the output is a little bit different from the image).

[image: A sample Dataset]

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.linspace(0,1500,16)
y1 = np.random.random((1,1,1,1,1,1,6,len(x)))
y2 = np.random.random((1,1,1,1,1,1,6,len(x)))
y3 = np.random.random((1,1,1,1,1,1,6,len(x)))
y4 = np.random.random((1,1,1,1,1,1,6,len(x)))

da1 = xr.DataArray(y1, dims=('MachineID','MachineType','Year','Month','Compensation','Axis','SensorID','Pos'),
                       coords={'MachineID':['Empty'],'MachineType':['Empty'],'Year':['Empty'],'Month':['Empty'],'Compensation':[0],
                            'Axis':['Empty'],'SensorID':range(6),'Pos':x},
                       name='val')

da2 = xr.DataArray(y2, dims=('MachineID','MachineType','Year','Month','Compensation','Axis','SensorID','Pos'),
                       coords={'MachineID':['MC_B'],'MachineType':['Car'],'Year':['2020'],'Month':['Aug'],'Compensation':[1],
                            'Axis':['X'],'SensorID':range(6),'Pos':x},
                       name='val')

da3 = xr.DataArray(y3, dims=('MachineID','MachineType','Year','Month','Compensation','Axis','SensorID','Pos'),
                       coords={'MachineID':['MC_C'],'MachineType':['Train'],'Year':['2020'],'Month':['Aug'],'Compensation':[1],
                            'Axis':['X'],'SensorID':range(6),'Pos':x},
                       name='val')

da4 = xr.DataArray(y4, dims=('MachineID','MachineType','Year','Month','Compensation','Axis','SensorID','Pos'),
                       coords={'MachineID':['MC_D'],'MachineType':['Train'],'Year':['2020'],'Month':['Aug'],'Compensation':[1],
                            'Axis':['X'],'SensorID':range(6),'Pos':x},
                       name='val')

#%%
df = pd.concat([da1.to_dataframe(), da2.to_dataframe(), da3.to_dataframe(), da4.to_dataframe()])
ds=xr.Dataset.from_dataframe(df)
ds
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: `ds.sel(MachineID=ds.MachineID != "Empty")` should get you started.